# Duplicate integer detection

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates, integer

Update: Wow that was fast! Thank you all for your input, totally overlooked that I was comparing an indice to a value. I’m aware of the shorter methods, the course that I’m on hasn’t shown us the “set” method so I wanted to accomplish the assignment with what was taught. I would upvote all of your comments if I had enough reputation points, thank you all so much!!

First off im an uber-noob to python. I'm learning for the sake of improving my networking administrating skills. The purpose of my code is to remove integers that occur more than once, and to create a new array that doesn't have any duplicate integers. However my code adds in all duplicates, instead of skipping them.

Code:

```
import array
my_list = [1,1,1,1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 7]

unique_list = []

dupe_list = []

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if i not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(my_list[i])

print("unique array is ", unique_list, 'n', "dupe list: ", dupe_list)
```

Output:

```
unique array is  [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 7] n dupe list:  []
```

So basically I have a for-loop that checks whether an integer that is in `my_list` is also in `unique_list`, if not then I want the code to add the integer in. However my code is adding every integer into the `unique-list` regardless of whether it is in there or not. Does the `not in` function not work the way I think it does?

Answer (score 2):

you can remove integers that occur more then once using `set`

```
>>> my_list = [1,1,1,1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 7]
>>> list(set(my_list))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there are easier ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, but your bug is because you're confusing indices and values.

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if i not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(my_list[i])
```

In the above code, `i` is the *index* of each item in `my_list`, but you're comparing it against the *values* in `unique_list`.  One of these things is not like the other!

If you wanted to iterate through by index, you need to use the subscript operator `[]` to get the value out of `my_list`:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(my_list[i])
```

It would however be simpler to just iterate through by value:

```
for v in my_list:
    if v not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(v)
```

And of course it's simpler yet to just do:

```
unique_list = list(set(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `dict.fromkeys()` to remove duplicates

`>>> my_list = [1,1,1,1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 7]`

`>>> list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))`

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`